# How do I merge changes to feature branch over to master branch in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git

In the accepted answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559119/how-to-resolve-conflicts-in-egit), does it only work for master branch or any other branch?

I am not seeing below line in my eclipse when trying to merge the master changes to my branch:

- Open the Git perspective
- In the Git Repository view, go to Branches → Local → master
- Right click → Merge...

Comment: What exactly can't you see? Could you show a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: I made the question grammatically correct and thereby clearer to read and understand

Comment: Edited some grammatical error in the body of the question.